# Is it possible to get a checkbox with Mechanize other than name attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I have been trying scraping with Ruby and Mechanize.
The websites I saw say that the way to get a checkbox and check it is below.

```
form.checkbox_with(:name => 'name').check
```

However, the checkbox that I would like to get does not have a name attribute.
Instead, it has a class attribute. Is it possible to do like below or is there any alternative ways to achieve it?

```
form.checkbox_with(:class => 'class_name').check
form.checkbox_with(:class_name => 'class_name').check
```

---

versions
rails: 5.2.4.4
ruby: 2.6.3
mechanize: 2.7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [source code](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/lib/mechanize/element_matcher.rb#L14) yes.

```rb
def elements_with singular, plural = "#{singular}s"
  class_eval <<-CODE
    def #{plural}_with criteria = {}
      selector = method = nil
      if String === criteria then
        criteria = {:name => criteria}
      else
        criteria = criteria.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h|
          case k = k.to_sym
          when :id
            h[:dom_id] = v
          when :class
            h[:dom_class] = v
          when :search, :xpath, :css
  ...
```

so you can use either

```rb
form.checkbox_with(class: 'class_name').check
# OR by xpath
form.checkbox_with(xpath: '//*[@id="someId"]/a[1]').check
# OR by id
form.checkbox_with(id: 'someId').check
```

Comment: Thank you very much for telling it to me. I do not know why, but I could not get the element with the way. I will try another one.